# Submit button and form not working when attempting to prevent page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I know there are numerous questions and answers on how to prevent page reload after form submit with AJAX but I just couldn't get mine to work. I've tried setting the button to `type: button` which just disables the button completely. When I try `onsubmit: return false` on the form, this results in nothing clicking the button. Using jQuery to prevent default also didn't work out. What I want is to send this email with PHP retrieving data from the form without the page from reloading. Any help would be highly appreciated.

### Form

```
<?php include('php/interuni_process.php');?>                 
  <form class="form_pro" action="index.php" method="post" role="form">

    <input type="text" class="form" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?= $email ?>">
    <div class="error"><?= $email_error ?></div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="action_button"></button>
 </form>
```

### PHP

```
    $email_error = "";
    $email = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


  if (empty($_POST["E-mail"])) {
    $email_error = "E-mail is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["E-mail"]);

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if ($email_error == '' ){
      unset($_POST['submit']);

      $to = " Whoever <$email>";
      $subject = 'Hello';
      $message = "Hello, $firstname!";

      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
       $email = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

I've also tried

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".form_pro").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/interuni_process.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: I added, check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to change the logic flow to do so.
try the following code which i have tested on my PC.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<form id="myData" class="form_pro" method="post" role="form">

    <input type="text" class="form" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" value="">
    <div class="error"></div>
    <button name="submit" type="button" class="action_button" onclick="doSubmit();">OK</button>
 </form>

<script>
    function doSubmit(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'interuni_process.php',
            data:$("#myData").serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if(data==="SUCCESS"){
                    $(".error").text("No error occurred");
                }else{
                    $(".error").text("Error occurred: "+ data);
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

and sample code for "interuni_process.php" is

```
<?php
    $eMail=$_POST["E-mail"];

    if($eMail===""){ //or whatever process condition you want to do
        echo "Email cannot be blank";
    }else{
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
?>
```

modify business logic as your per requirement

Comment: I though there would be atleast some form of loading time which tricked me thinking nothing was happening!

Comment: @Mahesh What happened if your form `action="some_other_url"` and you want o call ajax for a particular field to a different url?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You remove action from HTML `<form>` Tag

```
 <form class="form_pro" method="post" role="form">
```

after change add return false to your jquery function as per below

```
$(document).on('submit','.form_pro',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'interuni_process.php',
        type:'POST'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. This is extremely weird, when I press the submit button, nothing happens after I add the ajax code as seen in my question.

Comment: @LordGoderick i change my code check it any help for you

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I honestly don't know what's wrong with it. Pressing the buttons result in nothing.

Comment: Actually nevermind! It's working! It's so stealth that i thought nothing was happening haha, had to check my email personally.