# Preventing page refresh on form submission stops code from executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have read so many solutions about **preventing page reload from form submission**, most of them are to return false with a "JQuery script" or `preventDefault()`.

The problem is, if you prevent the page reload with Javascript or JQuery, the code won't be **executed**, so in my case, the email will not be sent. So, how could I run both?

Here is my HTML form.

```
 <form id="myform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
  <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="name" required name="name"></p>
  <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="email" placeholder="email" required name="email"></p>
  <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="subject" required name="subject"></p>
  <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="comment" required name="comment"></p>
  <p>
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
    </button>
```

My PHP code to collect data and send email:

```
<?php
$name = $email = $comment = $subject = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = form($_POST["name"]);
  $email = form($_POST["email"]);
  $subject = form($_POST["subject"]);
  $comment = form($_POST["comment"]);
  $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
  mail($to,$subject,$comment,$email);
}
function form($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#myform', function() {
      return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: You're looking for Ajax. Google it, there are plenty of tutorials. Since you're already using jQuery, you can use their wrapper.

Comment: Correct, if you stop the form submitting it wont submit. The idea is, once you stopped normal form submission, you make an AJAX call instead of allowing the form to do a normal submit. All you have done is stop anything at all happening.. Do a little research on AJAX. [Start here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/) THen once you understand the concept [check out jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789082/jquery-ajax-form-submit)

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: actually I found the answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198919/submit-button-and-form-not-working-when-attempting-to-prevent-page-reload

Answer (score 1):

I got this from here
http://remotephpdevelopers.com/blog/prevent-form-submission/

seems like something you are looking for. You just need to pass event through. Hope this helps

```
$(“#submitButton”).click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//do your thing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use $.ajax method for this without page load:

```
 $("#btn").click(function()
 {
 $.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'url',
data : $('#form').serialize() 
 });
```

});